# Facebook Connect: get total number of photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

The title is self explanatory. I know you can do a request to

```
/me/photos
```

with arguments for the `limit` and the `offset`, but is there any quick way of finding out the total number of photos? I want to pick a random selection of photos and I do not want to have to download all 500+ photos worth of metadata to the client to shuffle. The facebook API documentation has not offered me any joy.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you get the albums instead? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/
each album has a count property that says how many pictures it has.

Comment: Because most of my photos are uploaded piecemeal and not in any album. Or does "Albums" include these too? I was thinking it would only get the albums I uploaded myself.